# Problema con API Json de Chatfuel

Tags: php

tengo un problema con la API Json de Cahtfuel con PHP, no se si no me funciona, tal vez estoy haciendo algo mal o me falte algo, consiste en lo siguiente: tengo una entrada de usuario y un json api que esta con una url y el parámetro especificado por el usuario para consumir un json mediante GET (chatfuel exige su propio formato de atributos json) y el chatfuel al momento de probarlo me arroja el error de json "unable to parse json" y no me devuelve la respuesta deseada, gracias por su ayuda y les dejo el código php que hace el procedimiento.

```
<?php
    include 'config.php'; 
    $parametro_a_consultar = $_REQUEST["tienda"];           
    $sql = "SELECT id, description FROM negocio WHERE name LIKE '%$parametro_a_consultar%'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                  
        /* Acá se genera el json. */
        $json = '{
            "set_attributes": 
            {
                "id-tienda": "'.$row['id'].'",
                "descripcion-tienda": "'.$row['description'].'"
            }
        }'; 
        /**************************/
            echo $json; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Has probado tratar de hacer el json con json_encode, en lugar de generarlo a través de un string?

además tampoco se ve el momento en que estés haciendo una llamada get

Comment: No me funciona, ademas la llamada la hago desde chatfuel.

Comment: También tienes que cambiar el header a header('Content-Type: application/json');
Al inicio de tu aplicación.
Inténtalo así con tu forma y con json encode.

Comment: He agregado ambas cosas y aún no funciona.